# How to add % sign to Y axis?

Tags: r

[image]I would like the numbers on the Y-axis to have a percent sign next to them. How would I go about doing this?

```
H <- c(61,89,94,89) # Create the data for the chart.#
M <- c("Pre-Calculus",
       "College 
Algebra",
       "Intermediate 
 Algebra",
       "Elementary 
Algebra")

bp <- barplot(H, col =c("dodgerblue4" ),  ylim = range(0,110),
              names.arg = M, horiz = F,
              family="Arial", border = NA, xlim = range(0,5), las=1,
              axes = T, ylab = 'Passing Percent')

text(bp, H + 5, paste(H, "%", sep="")) #Automates data labels[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override creation of y-axis with `yaxt = 'n'` and create a custom y-axis.

```
par(las=1)
bp <- barplot(H, col =c("dodgerblue4" ),  ylim = range(0,110),
              names.arg = M, horiz = F,
              family="Arial", border = NA, xlim = range(0,5), las=1,
              axes = T, ylab = 'Passing Percent', yaxt = "n")
val <- seq(0, 100, 20)
text(bp, H + 5, paste(H, "%", sep=""))
axis(2, at = val, labels = paste0(val, '%'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make the % labels horizontal, like the original graph?

Comment: Yes, you can use `par(las=1)`. I have updated the answer.